# Calculating Average based on Month and ID in SQL

Tags: sql, count, distinct, average

I have a sample table like below and would like to do average based on `MONTH` of the `DATE` and `ID`.  Is there any way I could do this in SQL.

`Table:Input`

`DATE    ID  VOLUME
20080630    A   45
20080628    A   23
20080629    A   34
20080627    A   33
20080730    A   45
20080728    A   12
20080730    A   34
20080724    A   56
20080430    A   34
20080428    A   23
20080630    B   12
20080628    B   45
20080629    B   67
20080627    B   78
20080730    B   45
20080728    B   12
20080730    B   34
20080724    B   56
20080430    B   2
20080428    B   34`

`Table:Output`

`DATE    ID  VOLUME  AVERAGE
20080630    A   45  33.75
20080628    A   23  33.75
20080629    A   34  33.75
20080627    A   33  33.75
20080730    A   45  36.75
20080728    A   12  36.75
20080730    A   34  36.75
20080724    A   56  36.75
20080430    A   34  28.5
20080428    A   23  28.5
20080630    B   12  50.5
20080628    B   45  50.5
20080629    B   67  50.5
20080627    B   78  50.5
20080730    B   45  36.75
20080728    B   12  36.75
20080730    B   34  36.75
20080724    B   56  36.75
20080430    B   2   18
20080428    B   34  18`

Comment: Which is the type of the DATE column ? Is it a VARCHAR or DATE or something else?

Comment: @gil.fernandes it's DATE

Comment: What's your DBMSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this Query:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m'), id, avg(volume) from xxx1 
    group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m'), ID;
```

or

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m'), id, avg(volume) from xxx1 
    group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m'), ID
```

Explanation:

`DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')` extracts the month and year from the date. Whereas `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m')` extracts only the month. (I was not quite sure, if you want the month without the year).

Basically you extract the month and then group by it together with the id and calculate the average of the volume for these groups.

Comment: @dnoeth I have tested with MySQL actually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Standard SQL answer, as you didn't tag your DBMS:

```
AVG(VOLUME)
OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datecolumn)
                  ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datecolumn))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mssql server [then so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ee273/4)

```
select t1.*, t2.AVG
from TABLE1 t1
join
(
    SELECT avg(volume) as AVG, MONTH(date) as DATE
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY MONTH(date), ID
) t2 on MONTH(t1.DATE) = t2.DATE
```

The output will match the required. The query will select all columns from source table and will add GROUP BY one column.